# How to pad single-digit numbers with a leading 0

Tags: php, number-formatting, digits, zero-padding

I am looping an array of one-digit and two-digit numbers.

When printing these values, I need to ensure that all values are shown as two-digit numbers.

I need a solution to prepend zeros to the single-digit numbers but leave the two-digit numbers unchanged.

In other words, I want to "left pad" a numeric string to a minimum of two digits by adding zeros.

How can I change my code to render leading 0's for values 1 through 9?

```
<?php foreach (range(1, 12) as $month): ?>
    <option value="<?=$month?>"><?=$month?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Expected result:

```
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
```

Comment: There is no benefit in repeating the option's text as the `value` value. It is needless html markup bloat.  Javascript will still handle the data the same without the `value` attribute declared.  Only declare the `value` attribute if it differs from the option's text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php foreach (range(1, 12) as $month): ?>
  <option value="<?= sprintf("%02d", $month) ?>"><?= sprintf("%02d", $month) ?></option>
<?php endforeach?>
```

You'd probably want to save the value of `sprintf` to a variable to avoid calling it multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

Use either [`str_pad()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
echo str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

or [`sprintf()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
echo sprintf('%02d', $month);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern".  There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 3):

```php
array_map( function( $day ) {
    return str_pad( $day, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
}, range(1, 31) );
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 02
    [2] => 03
    [3] => 04
    [4] => 05
    [5] => 06
    [6] => 07
    [7] => 08
    [8] => 09
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 13
    [13] => 14
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 16
    [16] => 17
    [17] => 18
    [18] => 19
    [19] => 20
    [20] => 21
    [21] => 22
    [22] => 23
    [23] => 24
    [24] => 25
    [25] => 26
    [26] => 27
    [27] => 28
    [28] => 29
    [29] => 30
    [30] => 31
)
```

Works in PHP 5.3+. Try it yourself: https://3v4l.org/aE6HO

Answer (score 2):

```
$month = 1;
echo sprintf("%02d", $month);
out: 01
```

Use sprintf

Comment: This unexplained answer is demonstrating an "antipattern".  There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 1):

`if($month < 10) echo '0' . $month;`

or

`if($month < 10) $month = '0' . $month;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that does the job nicely without using `foreach()` expressly.

```php
$options = array_map( function( $hour ) {
    return str_pad( $hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
}, array_combine( range(1,12), range(1,12) ) );
```

With the result of:

```php
Array
(
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 02
    [3] => 03
    [4] => 04
    [5] => 05
    [6] => 06
    [7] => 07
    [8] => 08
    [9] => 09
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 11
    [12] => 12
)
```

Comment: I think it would make better sense to call `array_reduce()` instead of `array_map()` so that you can manage the associative keys without having to call `array_combine()` and generate two ranged arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like bouncing in and out of PHP tags when building my HTML markup. By including the option tags inside `printf()`, you never need to leave PHP.

```
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
    printf('<option>%02d</option>', $month);
}
```

Furthermore, there is no reason to declare the `value` attribute in your option tags because it is identical to the option's text value. Even without the `value` attribute, JavaScript will still be able to grab the `value` of the tag from the text.

Only declare the option's `value` attribute if is different from the option text.

Therefore, it would be appropriate to declare the `value` attribute if you left it as an un-padded integer like this:

```
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
    printf('<option value="%d">%02d</option>', $month, $month);
}
```

**More elegantly**, when using the same variable more than once, use an explicit "argnum" (argument number) followed by a literal dollar sign so that the variable is only passed into `printf()` once.

Single-quoted string (rendered as one line of HTML): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/E0XO8))

```
printf('<option value="%1$d">%1$02d</option>', $month);
```

Double-quoted string (notice escaped `$` before `d`): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HbMYj))

```
printf("<option value=\"%1\$d\">%1$02d</option>\n", $month);
```

A [Nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) string: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AqBUS))

```
$format = <<<'HTML'
<option value="%1$d">%1$02d</option>

HTML;

foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
    printf($format, $month);
}
```