# Parse m/d/Y date to assign day, month, year to variable

Tags: php, date

I'm currently getting the user's birthday from Facebook and storing it in the standard m/d/Y that Facebook supplies (Ex: 05/21/1982). I have an edit profile page in which I need to assign the day, month and year to 3 separate variables in order to allow the user to change his or her birthday as well as pre-select the correct birthday.

My code that pertains to only the days variable which I would want to be assigned to $days_var and in the above example of 05/21/1982 would be 05 is pasted below:

```
<?php
$days = range(1, 31);
foreach($days as $day) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo($day) ?>" <?php if ($days_var = $day){echo "selected='1'";}?> ><?php echo($day) ?></option>
<?
}
?>
```

Thanks.
EDIT: I have only given the days example but would obviously need the day, month and year variables.

Comment: Here is [a relevant read about creating select options from a range of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71790975/2943403).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're needing to parse the date string into its constituent components?  How about:

```
list($month_var, $days_var, $year_var) = explode('/', $dateString);
```

Answer (score 2):

See PHP's [datetime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) or the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions

Answer (score 1):

Like ddlshack says, use strtotime() and date(),

And for future references,

It's

```
if ($days_var == $day)
```

not

```
if ($days_var = $day)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be rather poor UX or result in tedious javascripting to provide three separate date component fields.  This is because not all month-year combinations have the same number of days.

Instead pass the full date expression to a single html `<input type="date" value="$date">` tag.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date for more information.

When it comes to presenting a date string to the end user, you are welcome to use any format you like.  When transferring the data between layers or pages of your application, standardize the data as `Y-m-d` -- this will improve processing functionality and codability in javascript, php, and sql.

---

If you'd rather ignore the good advice above, you can parse your date string with: ([Demos](https://3v4l.org/uZhOJ))

For potentially zero-padded month and day strings:

1. `sscanf($date, '%[^/]/%[^/]/%s', $m, $d, $y);`
2. `[$m, $d, $y] = explode('/', $date);`
3. `$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date);` then
   `$m = $dateObject->format('m');`
   `$d = $dateObject->format('d');`
   `$y = $dateObject->format('Y');`

For values directly cast as integer types:

```
sscanf($date, '%d/%d/%d', $m, $d, $y);
```