# How to create Array based on Number

Tags: arrays, laravel

I had a question about creating an array based on the number that was requested.

For example, if the number requested is '5', it will create a sequence in the array like this `[001,002,003,004,005)`

I'm using Laravel, I've been trying something like this and it doesn't work.

```
foreach($request->jumlah as $jumlah) {
        $storedetail = new DetailAlat();
        $storedetail->id_alat = $storealat->id_alat;
        $storedetail->sub_id_alat = $jumlah;
        $storedetail->created_by = Session::get('username');
        $storedetail->save();
}
```

I hope someone in here can help me

The error is:

> Call to a member function toArray() on string

Comment: Related (if not a legitimate duplicate): [How to pad single-digit numbers with a leading 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1830409/2943403) and [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1699958/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `range()` function to create an array with a sequence of numbers. However, to get the numbers in the format you want (001, 002, 003, etc.), you can use `array_map()` function with `sprintf()` to format the numbers.

```php
$number = 5;
$sequenceArray = range(1, $number);

$formattedArray = array_map(function($num) {
    return sprintf('%03d', $num);
}, $sequenceArray);

foreach($formattedArray as $num) {
    $storedetail = new DetailAlat();
    $storedetail->id_alat = $storealat->id_alat;
    $storedetail->sub_id_alat = $num;
    $storedetail->created_by = Session::get('username');
    $storedetail->save();
}
```

Comment: Why bother with two separate loops?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    DetailAlat::create([
        'id_alat' => $storealat->id_alat,
        'sub_id_alat' => sprintf('%03d', $i),
        'created_by' => Session::get('username')
    ]);
}
```

But for this to work you need to define $fillable property

```
class DetailAlat extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id_alat', 'sub_id_alat', 'created_by'];
}
```